# How can I access the previous elements of an element using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to acces san element's previous element that matches a given id..How can I achieve that? I tried the following code but it returning me undefined.. How can I fix this?

```
       <label>Durée du project (MM/DD/YYYY): De
                    <select name="month" class="Required">
                        <option>Aug</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="date" class="Required">
                        <option>31</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="Year" class="Required">
                        <option>2011</option>
                    </select>
                     <input type="hidden"  class="datepicker1" id="datepck1"/>
      </label>

  <script language="javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
         alert($("#datepck1").prev("select[name=date]").attr("name"));
  })

  </script>
```

Comment: Previous siblings, you mean? "Element's previous element" is ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) only matches the *immediately* previous sibling. You're looking for [prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/):

```
alert($("#datepck1").prevAll("select[name=date]").attr("name"));
```